# c# radiobuttonlist control

Tags: c#

I am relatively new to c# and the event handling concept.

Inside this function I need to get a reference to the RadioButtonList control that fired the event.
Also, need to retrieve information from the selected radiobutton from the control

TIA

```
protected void Option_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Option_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButtonList sourceRadioButtonList = (RadioButtonList)sender;

    string selectedOption = sourceRadioButtonList.SelectedValue;
}
```

For more info, see: [RadioButtonList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.aspx)